# How to mask delete on files in Subversion

Tags: svn

i am trying to setup a Subversion repository with Apache httpd, everything looks good so far. But there is one major bottleneck i am facing. The access rights to files is plane and painful. For any valid user to get and commit file we need to have rw access. And there is no provision to mask the delete option on files. Any user who has rw access can intentionally or by accident delete a file in the repository which is a threat. I am not sure how good is the hook scripts. With Subclipse client in eclipse i have the provision to browse through the archive and delete a file. How do i prevent this, or better handle use access over files in SVN archive. Please share your thoughts.
Thanks.

Comment: You do realize that even if something is deleted, it remains in the history and can be brought back? It doesn't disappear from the repository.

Comment: Yes Mike that's possible but i intended to have the addition and deletion of files to be under one person control termed configuration controller.

Answer (score 3):

If people can access *(i.e. "read" privilege)* your repository to make modifications *(i.e. "write" privilege)*, it seems normal that they can also delete files -- which is some kind of modification.

But, no matter what is done by anyone on your SVN repository, it's always possible to revert a modification : any modification can be "cancelled" -- even suppression/delete of files/directory.

So, if someone does anything *(be it a "wrong" modification, or a "wrong" deletion)*, there is always a way to revert to the previous revision of any file *(and not only the "previous" revision, but "any" revision)*.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and suggestion, Restoring back from history always helps us from nightmare but actually i was thinking of preventing accidents. Say with a team of 50 people when someone deletes a file intentionally or by mistake it is not notified to the Configuration controller unless he explicitly checks for it. That will be a overhead when done on a daily basis.